# 74hc595 with not connected pin

Tags: circuit-design, datasheet, shift-register, pinout, 74hc595

I've bought some 74HC595 in SOP-16 without directly looking at their [datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2201121500_Shenzhen-Fuman-Elec-74HC595D-_C2929943.pdf) and now that I have looked at it for my project I saw that it is marked that the OE and MR pin are not connected.

[image]

I would like to know if it is really possible that a specific IC like the 74HC595 does not have exactly the same pins available depending on the manufacturer or it's just a bad datasheet.
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: The (Chinese) manufacturer can do whatever they want, and the datasheet seems pretty clear that the pins are nc (both A and D versions).  If you have the chips in-hand, why not bench test it?  Errors do crop up in datasheets, but when spec'ing chips for a new design, the datasheet is golden - unless proven otherwise.

Comment: OE and MR are rarely used in straightforward applications, like output expansion for an MCU, so a chip without those could still be a success in many applications. I don't know how much assembly cost it would save to take a real 595 die and not bond out those two pads. However, a specially designed 595lite die without those functions may well save a good bit of silicon area, which would improve cost and yield significantly. The IC **ought** to have a different part number, as it's not fully function compatible with a true 595, but they have their own practices over there.

Comment: An MR is a "0" 8 bits shift, ok, not really needed. OE is not also really needed if one doesn't use the "paralleling" "register" option (same serial input, alternative parallel outputs). So, probably ok in quasi-all "normal"  use (?).